# Why 'awk' command is not returning anything to variable when used in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, awk

Currently I am working on a task in which i have to read zipped file and list its contents. I am using bash script code in my controller file `files = tar tf 3578336.tar.xz | awk -F'/' '{ for (i=1;i<5;i++) print "/"$i ; print "\n"}' ORS='' |grep "/"|uniq`. I am trying to get content using this command but I am unable to get the response in variable. If i am using `files = tar tf 3578336.tar.xz` then It returns all the contents. What I am trying to do is to list the directories and files according to their levels. It is like creating a file management system for a zipped file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag this question as related to ruby and ruby-on-rails?

Comment: Well I am using controller to do this. If anyone even related to ruby on rails has ever done this then Please help me. Otherwise, There is nothing like to disturb you. Sorry if you felt bad for this

Comment: `something | awk | grep | uniq` seems a bit overkilling. I don't know how ruby works, so `files = tar ...` is unknown to me, but if you want to get help on `awk`'s part, you need to provide some sample input.

Comment: Sample input is a zipped folder that i am using with it. Just copy and paste it in the terminal, replace the name of the zipped folder and you'll see results printing out. Is there any method to get those printed out variables into an array and return that array from this code. If it is possible then I might be able to assign that array into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some sample input/output data, to see what is what you want?

I don't have a *nix near but you can check if tar is writing the output to stderr or stdout, something like this:

```
tar tf 3578336.tar.xz 2>/dev/null   #If you can see the filenames, then it writes to stdout

tar tf 3578336.tar.xz >/dev/null   #If you can see the filenames, then it writes to stderr
```